# Enable SSL for a React Hosted App using npm serve

Tags: certbot, certbot-external-auth, certbot-dns-plugin

I have hosted my react app on google Cloud server `(ubuntu 18.04 LTS)` and associated my domain with that as well. I am trying to use certbot to SSL my website for free but unfortunately, everywhere I see it has tutorial for setting it up using `nginx` or `apache`. To serve my app I have used the simple commands:

```
sudo npm run build
sudo serve -s build --listen 80
```

Now I am struggling a bit to setup ssl for my react app, has anyone tried the same before?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have your certificate files I mean key.pem and certificate.cert you can start serve as below.

```
serve --ssl-cert /dir/to/certificate.crt --ssl-key /dir/to/key.pem  -s build -l 80
```